# Creating & Referencing JavaScript multidimensional arrays with in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, multidimensional-array

I pride my self in finding my own answers, but I give up. After trying every array notation I could find on Stack AND everywhere else I am still stuck. To sum it up how can I make this work by either this method or another? All methods tried work in IE and FF. None in chrome. This seems to be the most desired notation of the day.

```
var status=[
["#0f6122","0","GREEN"],
["#cbb924","1","YELLOW"],
["#f46906","2","ORANGE"],
["#990400","3","RED"],
["#585e72","4","DRKGREY"]
];

alert(status[3][2]); // I would assume should = RED instead it =’s “undefined”
```

Before Posting my plea for help, stacks pre-submission tips gave the code bellow as another alternative to still no avail in chrome, but fine in ie and ff.

```
var status=[];
status[0]= {};
status[0]["color"]="GREEN";
status[0]["code"]="#0f6122";
status[0]["level"]=0;

alert(status[0]['color']); // never get this far. get same message as trying to use associative arrays with chrome “can not Set Property”
```

ugggg

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3AVA/ If you're going to post code that represents the issue, please first make sure it represents the issue. Works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 21.0.1180.60 http://jsfiddle.net/Y3AVA/ Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/am-not-i-am

Comment: I apologize for leaving the impression that my above code was not a direct cut and paste from my file. It was and the errors were real ONLY in chrome. It failed on the first value assignment as stated above. I appologize for offending you.

Answer (score 3):

When pasting:

```
status=[
    ["#0f6122","0","GREEN"],
    ["#cbb924","1","YELLOW"],
    ["#f46906","2","ORANGE"],
    ["#990400","3","RED"],
    ["#585e72","4","DRKGREY"]
];
```

In chrome's console it does indeed fail silently, but that has more to do with the name of your variable: `status`, as you might imagine, is not exactly a safe variable name. When I changed it to `foo`, all was well.

That's why you should be careful with globals... when in doubt open up a browser window, open the console and type your variable name, if your variable name is auto-completed, don't use it!

PS: `foo[0]['color']` can be written as `foo[0].color`.

Comment: `window.status` has a getter and a setter: On setting a value, the value is turned into a string, and, if permitted, displayed in the status bar. A snippet to show serialization: `window.status={toString:function(){return 1}};console.log(status);` prints `"1"`.

Comment: of course, it's been a while since I used the `status`-bar! how could I forget, those good 'ol nineties with ghastly design, alerts and scrolling and flickering status' :)